# How to find the steady state in this system when one variable is irrelevant for equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-theory, steady-state

I have a nonlinear system of differential equations for functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ with parameters $\epsilon$ and $\lambda$

$$\frac{\text dx}{\text dt}=(1-x)\cdot[1-\epsilon x-2\lambda xy(1-x)]$$
$$\frac{\text dy}{\text dt}=-\lambda xy^2(1-x)$$

I'm trying to look at the steady state of this system. Looking at $\frac{\text dy}{\text dt}=0$ we have three cases: $x=0$, and $x=1$, and $y=0$

For $x=0$ we have $\frac{\text dx}{\text dt}=1$, so this cannot be a steady state.

For $y=0$ we have equilibrium at $x=1/\epsilon$ or $x=1$

For $x=1$, $\frac{\text dx}{\text dt}=0$ no matter what the other parameters or $y$ are equal to, and this is what I have a question on. From solving this numerically it looks like when $\epsilon<1$ we end up in this third case, and the equilibrium of $y$ depends on both $\epsilon$ and $\lambda$. However, since we have equilibrium when $x=1$ no matter what $y$ is, I am not sure how to determine the equilibrium value for $y$ given the parameters $\epsilon$ and $\lambda$.

How do we determine the steady state of $y$ here in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\lambda$ when $\epsilon<1$ and when $x=1$?

EDIT: I realize this also depends on the initial conditions. I am using $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$. Because of this it seems like this is not a simple task...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you talk about *the* steady state, do you mean which (if any) of the infinitely many equilibrium points that the solution converges to as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes. For the case where $\epsilon<1$, $x$ will go to $1$, but $y$ goes to different values depending on parameter values (and initial conditions). I didn't know if there was a way to express what y goes to in terms of these parameters

Comment: I see. You're right, that looks like a difficult problem. I would be surprised if there's a simple explicit formula. One would need to find a constant of motion, perhaps...